# Extract AIC from FitARMA in R

Tags: r

I apply *FitARMA* function from package *FitARMA* to certain time serie and I get the following result:

```
> model <- FitARMA(ts, c(1,0,1))
> model
ARIMA(1,0,1)
length of series = 1593 ,  number of parameters = 3
loglikelihood = 5113 ,  aic = -10220 ,  bic =  -10203.9
```

I want to extract aic to a variable. However there is no aic in model details ([screen with model details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUMJI.png)) neither any information about it in the package documentation.

Is there any possibility to do sth like `model_aic <- model$aic` since I want to do for loop for different p, q orders of ARMA, therefore I would like to extract aic to a variable instead of typing it from the console manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a function that computes the AIC of the FitARMA model

```
library(FitARMA)
model <- FitARMA(AirPassengers, c(1,0,1))
model
ARIMA(1,0,1)
length of series = 144 ,  number of parameters = 3
loglikelihood = -496.55 ,  aic = 999.1 ,  bic =  1008

AICFitARMA <- function(model){
  k <- nrow(coef.FitARMA(model))
  AIC <- 2 * k - 2 * model$loglikelihood
  return(AIC)
}

AICFitARMA(model)
[1] 999.0944
```